# Merge+unmerge cells to normalize table based on first column; insert newlines between merged content

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet with cells in some columns merged:

[image]

I need to normalize it, such that the cells in the first column are unmerged (those should be considered the true "rows"), but such that unmerged groups of cells (in these "rows") are put into a single cell with newlines to retain the list-like content:

[image]

Note that in some columns besides the first, there may also be some merged cells, but in any case the first column should determine what a "row" in the output sheet should look like.

Does such a VBA script exist to do this?

**UPDATE**: Here's a little pseudo-code for what I was thinking:

```
foreach row:
  determine height of merged cell in column A
  unmerge cell in column A (content is in top cell of range?)
  for each column after A:
    if cell is merged, unmerge (content is in top cell of range?)
    else concatenate cell contents with newline separator in top cell of row range
  cleanup excess rows from the unmerging
```

Unfortunately I think there's a bit of complexity in some of these steps.

**UPDATE#2**: Based on the accepted answer, I created some new code to accomplish my goals:

```
Sub dlo()
    Dim LastRow&, r&, c&, rowheight&, n&, Content$, NewText$
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For r = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(r, 1).MergeCells Then
            rowheight = Cells(r, 1).MergeArea.Cells.Count
            For c = 1 To LastCol
                NewText = vbNullString
                For rr = r To (r + rowheight - 1)
                    Content = Cells(rr, c)
                    Cells(rr, c) = vbNullString
                    NewText = NewText & vbCrLf & Content
                Next
                Cells(r, c).UnMerge
                Cells(r, c) = NewText
            Next
            'Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(k - 1, 2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            'LastRow = LastRow - rowheight + 1
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

The only thing I didn't finish was the deletion of resulting blank rows (I ended up just commenting those out since I knew a could just sort the table to eliminate the blanks).

If anyone has better ideas for how to describe this, please let me know so I can edit the title... I have a feeling this is not a rare need, so I'd like to help other find this.

Comment: Merged cells will have a `MergeArea.Rows.Count` >1 - offseting `MergeArea` by one column will give you the corresponding cells in ColB (not accounting for possible merged cells in other columns, but you'd need to be more specific about that)

Comment: @pnuts: I agree--merged cells stink.  The sheet I've been provided has the merged cells; the sheet I want to produce won't have merged cells... the actual content will be in a normal cells separated by newlines.  Besides the fact that the sheet is large, this can't be done without a script anyway because if I simply merged the cells, the content is concatenated without any separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you asking for?

```
Sub dlo()
Dim LastRow&, i&, j&, k&, n&, Content$, Text$
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Do
    i = i + 1
    Text = vbNullString
    If Cells(i, 1).MergeCells Then
        k = Cells(i, 1).MergeArea.Cells.Count
        n = Cells(i, 1).RowHeight
        For j = 1 To k
            Content = Cells(j + i - 1, 2)
            Cells(j + i - 1, 2) = vbNullString
            Text = Text & vbCrLf & Content
        Next
        Cells(i, 1).UnMerge
        Cells(i, 2) = Mid(Text, 3)
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(k - 1, 2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows(i).RowHeight = n * k
        NewLastRow = LastRow - k + 1
    End If
    DoEvents
Loop Until i = NewLastRow
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

The above code works fine to my dummy data.

Comment: Wow... thanks so much! It didn't exactly do what I was looking for, but you gave me enough structure to get where I needed to go.  I'll add the sourcecode I used above.

Comment: This seems like a horrible idea, at least from an analytical standpoint.  Maybe from a presentation standpoint it makes some sense.  Be careful of merged cells.  Eventually you are going to run into all kinds of problems with these kinds of things.